# Windows 8.1 Administrator

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, uac

I am evaluating Windows 8.1 for business purposes and there is one major drawback which I am running into.

In Windows 7 our users normally turn UAC all the way off so that they can edit files on the local C drive as some legacy systems we support drop files directly to C:\ via their secure VPN connections.

In Windows 8.1 I can't even edit my hosts file without opening notepad as administrator and then browsing to the location.

Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere? Otherwise I see absolutely no reason to upgrade my uses in the future as Windows 7 does exactly what I want.

Comment: You can disable UAC in Windows 8.1.  Windows 7 requires you to launch notepad as an Administrator also.  If you disable UAC in Windows 8.1 you wil disable the ability to launch Modern UI Applications.  Your users should get out of the habit of placing personal files in the C directory, user profiles should be used, to make backing up easier.

Comment: In Windows 7 I disable UAC and then DO NOT have to open notepad as an administrator to open a file on the C drive or anywhere else in order to edit and save. In 8.1 I have turned the UAC slider all the way down and still get a permission denied error if I attempt to edit/save a file.

Comment: Saving files in the C:/ directory was, like, from the MS-DOS days. That was way out of fashion even in Windows 95.

Comment: And there are some large legacy systems that our clients utilize which predate Windows 95. I can't change their system, and make it save somewhere else.

Comment: @MitchMiller - Yes I know if you disable UAC you don't need to open as an Administrator. That As I indicate you have to actually disable it, which will disable your ability to launch Modern UI applications, the slider no longer disables UAC because of the Windows Store.

Answer (score 3):

Disable it with this.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Use at your own risk, void where prohibited by law.  If you break anything, I'm telling the judge I warned yah.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the slider to the bottom doesn't disable the UAC in Windows 8(.1) any longer. YOu have to set the value `EnableLUA` in the registry from `1` to `0`. But this disables the new Store Apps.

Comment: ...which defeats the purpose of Windows 8(.1).

Comment: Where do I find this setting in the registry? I could care less if it disables store apps as we don't use those for business purposes.

Comment: @MitchMiller - I was able to find the EnableLUA key when I did a search in my registry.  I didn't write down the location of the key.

Comment: @MitchMiller http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0aeac9d8-3591-4294-b13e-825705b27730/how-to-disable-uac?forum=winserversecurity